# VSTO: How do I get the user I create an outlook appointment for?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I right click a colleagues calendar and clicks "create appointment".

Now I have the inspector and the Outlook.AppointmentItem, but I can't figure out how to get the user of the calendar I created the appointment for.

Sometimes the Outlook.AppointmentItem.Recipients has the user and sometimes not.

Any idea how to get the username?

Answer (score 0):

The [AppointmentItem.Organizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/appointmentitem-organizer-property-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the AppointmentItem class returns returns a string representing the name of the organizer of the appointment.

Also you may find the [How to: Get the Organizer of a Meeting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184615.aspx) article helpful.